# What is the cause of Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement and how is it fixed?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

I am relatively new to java and am coding a game. It was going quite well until I ran into an error under a } and a ; saying

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement
```

(with a ; for the ;). I am wondering what creates syntax errors, what are they and how are they fixed. I would apreciate any feedback and understand if this is a dumb question. Thanks.

Comment: We don't have magic ball in hand. Show us your code to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Most of the time, a `{` needs a matching `}`. Errors can be difficult to spot in poorly indented code.

Comment: As you have mentioned you don't even know what syntax errors are, you should probably go for reading some basic computer fundamental books rather than directly jumping to code. To start after learning the fundamentals will help you in long run :)

Comment: @dotvav you have helped me understand thank you.

Comment: @justcurious I will take your advice and see if my local library has anything that can help me. I did an online course but they never said anything about this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors are errors on compile-time. It means that your compiler is seeing a gravure mistake in your Syntax and therefore will not compiling your code. 
Now to your specific errormessage:

-every task in Java ends with a semicolon "`;`".
-the body of classes, methods and iterations is define with curly braces "`{`","`}`".

if your Syntax error tells you, that your method/classbody is not closed and you have to insert a curly brace "`}`" to do so, than there is no room for questions at all!

I dont want to further explain this stuff, because thats the VERY basic and is written in every java tutorial!

Comment: And "task" is poor word choice.

Comment: that was a typo, thanks. Im not good in english if you want to edit my answere do so, I apreciate help

Comment: I did do a beginner and intermediate course in java however they never covered these errors because it was more orientated as telling you what different statements are and how you use them.

Comment: :D java is like learning an actual languish, you will have to read some books till you have the wisdom about how java is processing :) I started like you myself so dont worry

Comment: @ethn_da_ninja When you were learning how to write: did they tell you about all the ways to make spelling errors? - How to write correct Java statements is available in formal and not-so-formal definitions. Consult them while you are a novice.